# ExpandableListView и группы разных по типу объектов

Tags: ооп, android, java

Здравствуйте!

У меня в проекте есть (к примеру) 4 типа данных: стул, стол, диван, кушетка, все они наследники класса мебель.
Нужно в одном окне отобразить список мебели, разделённый по группам(стулья, столы и тд).
Для этого использую ExpandableListView, и расширяю BaseAdapter. До этого адаптер получал String и проблем не было(ну конечно). Теперь же, я хочу в этот один адаптер, отправлять списки объектов вышеупомянутых типов, обращаясь к которым, я смогу заполнять подгруппы.
Т.е. выглядит вот так:

```
Стулья
  стул 1
  стул 2
Столы
  стол 1
Диваны
  диван 1
```

....
Когда использовал один тип данных делал вот так:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> groups = new ArrayList<>();
 List<String> mChair= new ArrayList<>();
 List<String> mTable= new ArrayList<>();
....
groups.add(mChair);
groups.add(mTable);
```

И **groups** в адаптер, вместе с контекстом.

И когда нужно было отобразить на экране:

```
  groups.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition));
```

А как теперь отправить в адаптер списки объектов, и объединить их в группы.

*Проще говоря, как мне отправить объекты **разных типов** в адаптер, и получить нужные данные из этих объектов для отображения в списке со своим list item`ом?*

Answer (score 1):

К примеру, так:

```
/** названия групп мебели */
    String[] stul; //1. Стул
    String[] diwan; //2. диван

    /** названия групп мебели */
    String[] mebelGroups;
    /** коллекция для групп */
    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> groupData;

    /** коллекция для элементов одной группы */
    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> childDataItem;

    /** общая коллекция для коллекций элементов */
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Map<String, String>>> childData;

    /** список атрибутов группы или элемента */
    Map<String, String> m;
    ExpandableListView explvMebel;

/** Группы операторов */

mebelGroups = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.mebelGroups); // Массив из типов мебели

/** Компоненты групп */
        stul= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.stulArray); //1. Массив стульев
        diwan= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.diwanArray); //2. Массив диванов

/** заполняем коллекцию групп из массива с названиями групп */
        groupData = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        for (String group : mebelGroups) {
/** заполняем список атрибутов для каждой группы */
            m = new HashMap<String, String>();
            m.put("groupName", group);
            groupData.add(m);
        }

/** список атрибутов групп для чтения */
        String groupFrom[] = new String[] {"groupName"};
/** список ID view-элементов, в которые будет помещены атрибуты групп */
        int groupTo[] = new int[] {android.R.id.text1};

/** создаем коллекцию для коллекций элементов */
        childData = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Map<String, String>>>(); // типы стульев

/** 1. Стулья коллекция */
        childDataItem = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        // заполняем список атрибутов для каждого элемента
        for (String operChild : stul) {
            m = new HashMap<String, String>();
            m.put("mebelName", operChild);
            childDataItem.add(m);
        }
        // добавляем в коллекцию коллекций
        childData.add(childDataItem);

/** 2. диванов коллекция */
        childDataItem = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        for (String operChild : diwan) {
            m = new HashMap<String, String>();
            m.put("mebelName", operChild);
            childDataItem.add(m);
        }
        childData.add(childDataItem);
    /** список атрибутов элементов для чтения */
        String childFrom[] = new String[] {"mebelName"};
/** список ID view-элементов, в которые будет помещены атрибуты элементов */
        int childTo[] = new int[] {android.R.id.text1};

        SimpleExpandableListAdapter adapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
                this,
                groupData,
                android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,
                groupFrom,
                groupTo,
                childData,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                childFrom,
                childTo);
        explvMebel = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);
        explvMebel.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Вроде бы так. Это рабочий код просто для отображения. Я себе еще прикручивал автозакрытие ранее открытых, если понадобится, то могу поделиться.